# Returning a nil from an optional generic extension

Tags: swift, generics, option-type

Here's something I'm playing with. The problem is that I have a container class that has a generic argument which defines the type returned from a closure. I want to add a function that is only available if they generic type is optional and have that function return a instance containing a nil.

Here's the code I'm currently playing with (which won't compile):

```swift
open class Result<T>: Resolvable {

    private let valueFactory: () -> T

    fileprivate init(valueFactory: @escaping () -> T) {
        self.valueFactory = valueFactory
    }

    func resolve() -> T {
        return valueFactory()
    }
}

public protocol OptionalType {}
extension Optional: OptionalType {}

public extension Result where T: OptionalType {

    public static var `nil`: Result<T> {
        return Result<T> { nil } // error: expression type 'Result<T>' is ambiguous without more context
    }
}
```

Which I'd like to use like this:

```swift
let x: Result<Int?> = .nil
XCTAssertNil(x.resolve())
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: How is `Result` defined? Moreover, why do you need a wrapper protocol around `Optional`?

Comment: What is it you’re trying to do here with the OptionalType? I feel like that is unneeded and there is a better way to solve your underlying problem.

Comment: Yep. Understand guys. But I'm playing with a DSL concept so I need to describe a nil as well as return it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this with a static property, however you can achieve it with a static function:

```swift
extension Result {
    static func `nil`<U>() -> Result where T == U? {
        return .init { nil }
    }
}

let x: Result<Int?> = .nil()
```

Functions are way more powerful than properties when it comes to generics.

---

**Update** After some consideration, you can have the static property, you only need to add an associated type to `OptionalType`, so that you'd know what kind of optional to have for the generic argument:

```swift
protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
}

extension Optional: OptionalType { }

extension Result where T: OptionalType {
    static var `nil`: Result<T.Wrapped?> {
        return Result<T.Wrapped?> { nil }
    }
}

let x: Result<Int?> = .nil
```

One small downside is that theoretically it enables any kind of type to add conformance to `OptionalType`.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked a treat. Thanks.